# spark-submit File transfer from local to cluster

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using spark-submit cluster mode to submit a job from local to spark cluster. There are input files, output files, and job log files that I need to transfer back and forth between local machine and spark cluster.

Any recommendation methods to use file transferring. Is there any future plan that spark will support file transferring from cluster to local and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Use HDFS to share files on your cluster. It is the most widely use distributed filesystem for Spark.

You can upload files from your local machine to the remote HDFS cluster.